# Prove: $\sum_{\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_N} e^{a\sigma_1}\cdots e^{a\sigma_N}=2\prod_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{\sigma_i}e^{a\sigma}$ where $\sigma_i \in \{-1,1\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, exponential-function, factoring

In this Wikipedia article on the [one dimensional Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Ising%27s_exact_solution) they use the following factorization

$$
\displaystyle \sum_{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_N} e^{a\sigma_1}
e^{a\sigma_2}\cdots e^{a\sigma_N} = 2\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{\sigma_i}e^{a\sigma_i} = 2 \left[e^{-a}+e^{a}\right]^N \,.
$$
The first sum is over all possible sequences ($\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots, \sigma_N)$ where $\sigma_i \in \{-1,1\}$.

Does somebody have a reference for this factorization and/or able to give a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor $2$ is not plausible. Taking $N=1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma_1}e^{a\sigma_1}=e^{a}+e^{-a}
\end{align*}

> In general we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_N)\in\{-1,1\}^N}}&\color{blue}{e^{a\sigma_1}e^{a\sigma_2}\cdots e^{a\sigma_N}}\\
> &=\sum_{\left(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_N\right)\in\{-1,1\}^N}\prod_{j=1}^Ne^{a\sigma_j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{{S\subseteq[N]}\atop{|S|=k}}e^{ak}e^{-a(N-k)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k}e^{ak}e^{-a(N-k)}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(e^a+e^{-a}\right)^N}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the product symbol $\prod_{j=1}^N$ to write the product of $N$ factors.
- In (2) we reorder the sum by selecting all subsets $S\subseteq [N]=\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ for which the sign is positive and $[N]\setminus S$ for which the sign is negative.
- In (3) we use the fact that there are $\binom{N}{k}$ subsets $S\subseteq [N]$ with size $k$.
- in (4) we apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: In the source equation, the factor of $2$ is on both sides.

Comment: @aschepler: To me it seems the factor $2$ is missing at the left-most sum.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler than you're probably thinking. Each sum $\sum_{\sigma_i} e^{a \sigma_i}$, over the set $\sigma_i \in \{-1,1\}$ is just a sum of two terms $e^{-a} + e^a$. This is the same value for every $i$, so it just gets multiplied $N$ times.

$$ \prod_{i=1}^N \sum_{\sigma_i} e^{a \sigma_i} = (e^{-a} + e^a)^N $$